# How do I pass multiple arrays to a 'foreach' loop in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I want to write items from two arrays into a file, like

```
 @a = ('1', '2', '3')
 @b = ('0.1', '0.2', '0.3')
```

I want my output like this:

```
1 0.1
2 0.2
3 0.3
```

in the file.

I tried using two `foreach` loops, which is obviously wrong,

```
 foreach my $a (@a) {
    foreach my $b (@b) {
        print FP "$a $b \n";
    }
 }
```

This is wrong. How do I pass multiple arrays to a `foreach` loop in Perl?

Comment: Sidenote; don't use `$a, $b, @a, and @b` for variable names as some of them are predefined globals and therefore could induce misbehavior.

Comment: its just example...I have used other names in my program. thank you between!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to output all elements of `@a` and `@b` in parallel, you can loop through all indices of one of them (arrays are of same size so it doesn't matter which), and use it to access actual elements (`$a[$i]` and `$b[$i]`)

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#a) {
  print "$a[$i] $b[$i] \n";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
@a=('1','2','3');
@b=('0.1','0.2','0.3');

print "$a[$_] $b[$_] \n" for (0 .. $#a);
```

Of course this assumes @a and @b are of equal lengths.